# Обязательный входной параметр в get-запросе. Как правильно записать, если нужна фильтрация внутри кода по айди? Dart

Tags: get, https, flutter, dart

Подскажите, пожалуйста как верно решить такую задачу: нужно отфильтровать точки остановки, но никак не выходит сделать это правильно. Что сделано: выбрана дата поездки, выбран транспорт и выбран маршрут. Изучив АПИ понял что, чтобы отфильтровать остановки по каждому маршруту, нужно:
1)определить для какого дня нужен маршрут (это сделано)
2)определить действующий вариант маршрута для данного маршрута (тоже сделано). Далее по коду маршрута: например, 58 и сегодняшней дате определил, что действует вариант маршрута 769.

3. Далее по модели  RaceCard  получаем все остановки по 769 номеру по каждому направлению.

С третьим пунктом как раз и есть проблема. По АПИ требуется обязательный входной параметр в get-запрос. Как правильно его оформить?

Я делаю сейчас так:
Здесь **mv_id** - это обязательный входной параметр, но когда я делаю вот так:

http://mylink/getRaceList.php?fmt=json&mv_id - выдает ошибку

Но когда ввожу так, то все работает:
http://mylink/getRaceList.php?fmt=json&mv_id=1

Но мне нужен список отфильтрованного маршрута, а не только первый. Как правильно задать параметр?

Пишу на Dart'е, пробовал объединять модели, но это не срабатывало, сейчас пытаюсь фильтровать при помощи `where` метода, но фильтрация работает, если нет обязательного входного параметра.

Модели про которые говорю:

```
class ScheduleVariants {
  int mvId;
  int mrId;
  String mvDesc;
  DateTime mvStartdate;
  DateTime mvEnddate;
 }

class RaceCard {
  int mvId;
}
```

Comment: В чем именно затруднения - в фильтрации, в формировании query строки HTTP-запроса, или в написании конструктора (какого класса из двух приведенных)?

Comment: @yar85 в формировании скорее http-запроса. Не понимаю как правильно поместить этот обязательный параметр, чтобы точно 6н указывать, что мне нужно именно маршрут номер 21, например. А чтобы оно автоматически внутри кода это делало. Так можно сделать?

Comment: `final uri = Uri.https(хостнейм, '/getRaceList.php', { 'fmt': 'json', 'mv_id': твояПеременная.toString() });` и далее `http.get(uri, ....);` - предполагаю базовый http-клиент, а во всяких dio передача мапы с query-параметрами выполняется иначе (в последнем случае, см. документацию используемого пакета).

Comment: Естессно, если схема действительно `http:`, то надо вызывать `Uri.http` вместо `Uri.https`. Доки [тут](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html). Еще я не помню точно, как у базового http-клиента метод называется: `get` или `getUrl`, сориентируйся на месте :) код отправки запроса у тебя уже есть по всей видимости, раз что-то отправлял... осталось только сравнить формирование объекта `Uri`.

Comment: Насчет обязательности не совсем понятно, т.к. в модельных классах типы не nullable (линтер должен кричать если в конструкторе это int-свойство ожидается но не передается аргументом), и "включение обязательности" тут видимо сводится к простой пометке одного из параметров вызова (своего метода отправки запроса) ключевым словом `required` - не могу угадать какие с этим могут быть проблемы, даже теоретически...

Comment: Хотя, свойства модельных классов тут почему-то мутабельны... а значит, возможна любая фигня с ними (конечно, так лучше не делать, лучше за`final`ить все кроме вычисляемых свойств - последние можно считать в конструкторе/ините и исп. `late`, либо реализовать геттерами... с иммутабельными моделями просто легче бизнеслогику программить, т.к. большинство ошибок видно сразу в дизайнтайме).

Comment: @yar85 спасибо.  да, уже делал запросы, использую Uri.http. У базового пакета get, да. Да, проблема в том, что АПИ такой дизайн имеет, что лучше бы вообще его не имело, там где вообще не возможно вылазит null, постоянно приходится дебажить и бороться с null. Насчёт required this.mvId что-то как-то не додумался, ужк давно с этой проблемой сижу, глаз замылился.

Comment: Дизайн сетевой апишки вовсе не обязывает использовать мутабельные модели... зачастую, данные от апи требуются в исходном виде (как получены), особенно когда эти данны нужны в нескольких местах. То есть, имеет смысл выстраивать логику "вокруг" иммутабельных (вместо того чтобы держа единую/общую модель, менять ее в множестве мест и путаться в порядке/зависимостях). Для работы с дин. значениями, можно создавать производные классы: например, с фабричным методом принимающим иммутабельную модель (для извлечения исходных данных), и с методом обратной конвертации в такую модель (для отправки апишке).

Comment: ...и так как конвертация получится только в двух местах (`fromJson` модельного класса + `toXyzModel` в классе провайдера с дин. полями), будет легче находить и устранять ошибки с данными. Как связанные с типами и `null` значениями, так и прочие. Уже не надо будет скакать по коду на отладчике и всюду пихать `if (a.b == null)` или `a?.b ?? someFallback` затыкая стихийно возникающие в рантайме ошибки :) _//Может есть и более удобные способы, чем инициализация экземпляров других классов моделью, но этот имхо самый простой, и в небольших проектах он по-моему вполне удобен._

Comment: Для каждого экрана приложения я завожу класс контроллера, который использует данные от иммутабельных моделей либо напрямую (только чтение) либо через промежуточный "ролевой" провайдеркласс (чтение + запись/отправка)... Таким образом и ответственности распределяются по трем основным слоям (при правках легко найти нужный класс), и переиспользование облегчается (одни и те же провайдерные объекты у меня могут использоваться несколькими контроллерами). Повторюсь, не могу сказать насколько хороша эта практика, я сам новичок, но она обладает как минимум двумя преимуществами над изменяемыми моделями.